# Extension and bound of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-it_{1}}e^{-it_{2}} (s + b t_{1}t_{2})^{-g} dt_{1} dt_{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some problem which needs to be resolved 
to some extent.

The problem is to find an extension and bound of
a function of the form
\[
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-it_{1}}e^{-it_{2}} (s + b t_{1}t_{2})^{-g} dt_{1} dt_{2}
\]
where g > 0, as $b \to e^{\pi i}$.

All I know is that this is convergent for
s, b positive.

It seems to be better to replace paths by the negative imaginary axis.
But if I do so, then the factor $(s + b t_{1}t_{2})^{-g}$
goes across the negative real axis, which for me with
undergraduate complex analysis looks like a difficulty.

Is there any way we could handle this function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mc{I} & \equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic t_{1}}\expo{-\ic t_{2}}
\pars{s + bt_{1}t_{2}}^{-g}\,\dd t_{1}\,\dd t_{2} = 
{2^{2g} \over s^{g}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\pars{t_{1} + t_{2}}}
\over \pars{4 + 4bt_{2}t_{1}/s}^{g}}\,\dd t_{1}\,\dd t_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\omega\pars{t_{1} + t_{2}}/2}
\over \pars{4 + 4t_{2}t_{1}}^{g}}\,\dd t_{1}\,\dd t_{2}\qquad
\mbox{where}\quad\omega \equiv 2\root{s \over b}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mc{I} & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\omega\pars{t_{1} + t_{2}}/2}
\over \bracks{4 + \pars{t_{1} + t_{2}}^{2} - \pars{t_{1} - t_{2}}^{2}}^{g}}
\,\dd t_{1}\,\dd t_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{t_{2}}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}/2}
\over \bracks{4 + t_{1}^{2} - \pars{t_{1} - 2t_{2}}^{2}}^{g}}
\,\dd t_{1}\,\dd t_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}/2}
\int_{0}^{t_{1}}{1 \over \bracks{4 + t_{1}^{2} - \pars{t_{1} - 2t_{2}}^{2}}^{g}}
\,\dd t_{2}\,\dd t_{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}/2}
\int_{-t_{1}/2}^{t_{1}/2}{1 \over \pars{4 + t_{1}^{2} - 4t_{2}^{2}}^{g}}
\,\dd t_{2}\,\dd t_{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}/2} \over \pars{t_{1}^{2} + 4}^{g - 1/2}}
\int_{0}^{t_{1}/2}{1 \over \bracks{1 - 4t_{2}^{2}/\pars{4 + t_{1}^{2}}}^{g}}
{2 \over \root{t_{1}^{2} + 4}}\,\dd t_{2}\,\dd t_{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{2g} \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}/2} \over \pars{t_{1}^{2} + 4}^{g - 1/2}}
\int_{0}^{t_{1}/\root{t_{1}^{2} + 4}}{1 \over \pars{1 - t_{2}^{2}}^{g}}
\,\dd t_{2}\,\dd t_{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{4 \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}} \over \pars{t_{1}^{2} + 1}^{g - 1/2}}
\int_{0}^{t_{1}/\root{t_{1}^{2} + 1}}{1 \over \pars{1 - t_{2}^{2}}^{g}}
\,\dd t_{2}\,\dd t_{1}
\end{align}

> The $\ds{t_{2}}$-integral can be evaluated, by some CAS, in terms of the
>   [*Hypergeometric Function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $\ds{{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}}$. Namely,

\begin{align}
\mc{I} & =
{4 \over bs^{g - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{t_{1} \over \pars{t_{1}^{2} + 1}^{g}}\,\,\,
{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{%
{1 \over 2},g;{3 \over 2};{t_{1}^{2} \over t_{1}^{2} + 1}}
\expo{-\ic\omega t_{1}}\,\dd t_{1}
\end{align}

> I guess that's all we can do for awhile !!!.

Comment: I see a few problems in the beginning of your argument. If we let $\omega = 2 (s/b)^{1/2}$, then how come $i \omega (t_{1} +  t_{2})$ in the exp divided by 2 ? Also, in the second line of equations from above, where did the part $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{t_{1}}$ go?